# Cross check one's manager

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns: `employee_email`, `manager_email` - which indicate who is manager of a particular employee.

I want to avoid cases that at one row, A is B's manager; but in another row, B is A's manager.

I tried to use the following but it doesn't seem right

```
select *
from chart c1, chart c2
where c1.employee_email = c2.manager_email
and c1.manager_email = c2.employee_email
```

Thank you

Comment: *A is B's manager; but in another row, B is A's manager* how is that possible BTW?

Comment: "doesn't seem right". you should be able to verify if it's right or not - no need to guess. And if it's not right, show the results you vs what you want to achieve, given a set of sample data.

Comment: What do you mean "Avoid" do you want your query to return any such instance?  Are you trying to setup a constraint that would prevent such an occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

Is this you need:

```
select *  -- select columns here
from chart c1 left join chart c2
on c1.employee_email = c2.manager_email
and not exists (
    select 1 from chart c 
    where c.manager_email = c1.employee_email
    and c.employee_email = c2.manager_email
);
```